# cannot find symbol class Currency (enum)

Tags: java, android, enums, android-studio

I am using an enum class as following:

```
public enum Currency {

        INR(100, '₹'),
        USD(100, '$'),
        EUR(100, '€' );


    private final char currencySymbol;
    private final int subUnitsPerUnit;

    private Currency(int subUnitsPerUnit, char currencySymbol) {
        this.subUnitsPerUnit = subUnitsPerUnit;
        this.currencySymbol = currencySymbol;
    }

    public final char getCurrencySymbol() {
        return this.currencySymbol;
    }

    public final int getSubUnitsPerUnit() {
        return this.subUnitsPerUnit;
    }
}
```

and using following code in my fragment (in android) to use it:

```
private Currency currency = Currency.INR;
```

Both enum and fragment are in same package but when I run the app I keep getting the following error in Android Studio 0.8.6

```
Error:(44, 13) cannot find symbol class Currency
Error:(44, 33) cannot find symbol variable Currency
```

Can please somebody point me in right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're not declaring `Currency` within another class?

Comment: Check that you are not importing java.util.Currency by mistake?

Comment: @JonSkeet Nope, not declaring in another class. It's a separate file Currency.java and if it helps IDE recognises the class in editor but errors occur on runtime.

Comment: @NickPalmer Nope not importing java.util.Currency or any other Currency for that matter.

Comment: My next guess is that Android Studio is not compiling your Currency class correctly. Double check the file ending, and make sure that the folder the source is in is "blue" in Android Studio, indicating that it is being used as a source folder. Consider running Tools -> Android -> Sync Project With Gradle Files to make sure the correct source folders are being identified.

Comment: Did you try to change the Currency class name just to make sure it is not being confused with another class?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Yay! Thanks it was a naming conflict. I replaced the Currency enum name to another variable and problem solved. Thanks to all for your comments. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `Currency` class name and try to run the code again just to make sure it is not naming conflict.

Answer (score 0):

#### Change enum class name

Earlier I had an enum object as defined below:

```kotlin
object Enums{

    enum class X{
    }
    
    enum class Y{
    }
}
```

I just redefined object Enums to TypesEnums.

> Basically, change the enum class name to anything but Enum/Enums.